# Scale down retina sprite

Tags: css, sprite, retina-display

Is it possible to have one sprite file with both regular and retina sized icons?

I'm trying the following

```
.facebook { width:24px; height:24px;;background-position: -151px -227px;}

@media
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) {
    .facebook { background-position: -117px -169px;background-size: 24px 24px; }
}

.sprite {
    background-image: url("img/sprite.png?ver=10");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

html

```
<span class="sprite facebook">
</span>
```

But on an IOS device the icon does not appear if I have the background size on. And if I delete the background size it will display but not scaled down.

What am i doing wrong ? is it because they are in the same sprite.png ?

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle. Chrome developer tools will help with emulation for debugging....

Comment: Sorry I can't post the sprite but I hope someone can answer my question anyway. I'm testing with IOS simulator and a real iphone. Same result

Comment: Can you try background size 200% for retina devices.. Cannot give you assured solution without testing myself...

Comment: That did not give any result either. The icon dispappears when the background-size is on. Or it shows double size when it's not...